# NetBeans - "sun-resources.xml" vs. "glassfish-resources.xml"

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, deployment, glassfish-4

Do you know how Netbeans decides which filename to use for the application-scoped resources: *sun-resources.xml* or *glassfish-resources.xml*?
Is this name configurable or hard-coded?

As far as I understand GlassFish supports *sun-resources.xml* for backward compatibility. But according to "Application Deployment Guide" preferred filename is *glassfish-resources.xml*.

I run relatively recent version of Netbeans - 8.0.2 with GlassFish 4.1, but I get generated *sun-resources.xml* file. This looks odd and confusing.

On the other hand I've seen people having troubles with *glassfish-resources.xml*:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243034.
And the recommended solution is to rename *glassfish-resources.xml* to *sun-resources.xml* - also contradicting with GlassFish recommendations.

Best Regards

Comment: Starting a bounty, I want to understand this as well.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's set the expectation that in the Netbeans source, [Glassfish is supposed to be able to use both files](http://grepcode.com/file/bits.netbeans.org/maven2/org.netbeans.modules/org-netbeans-modules-glassfish-common/RELEASE80/org/netbeans/modules/glassfish/common/CommonServerSupport.java#CommonServerSupport). The server configuration is generally packaged in the [`CommonServerSupport`](http://grepcode.com/file/bits.netbeans.org/maven2/org.netbeans.modules/org-netbeans-modules-glassfish-common/RELEASE80/org/netbeans/modules/glassfish/common/CommonServerSupport.java) class.

Also, it's not configurable.

From what I can see in the Netbeans source however, the `glassfish-resource.xml` file is never going to be used. Here's why:

1. **The default setting should be the `glassfish-resource.xml`**, based on what I can infer from the [`deployResources()`](http://grepcode.com/file/bits.netbeans.org/maven2/org.netbeans.modules/org-netbeans-modules-glassfish-javaee/RELEASE80/org/netbeans/modules/glassfish/javaee/ResourceRegistrationHelper.java#78) method. This method in turn depends on [`registerResourceDirs()`](http://grepcode.com/file/bits.netbeans.org/maven2/org.netbeans.modules/org-netbeans-modules-glassfish-javaee/RELEASE80/org/netbeans/modules/glassfish/javaee/ResourceRegistrationHelper.java#110)
2. The problem starts when [`succeeded`](http://grepcode.com/file/bits.netbeans.org/maven2/org.netbeans.modules/org-netbeans-modules-glassfish-javaee/RELEASE80/org/netbeans/modules/glassfish/javaee/ResourceRegistrationHelper.java#111) is never updated to `true` to indicate that `glassfish-resource.xml` was successfully created and should be used.
3. What then ends up happening is that `deployResources()` tries to use `sun-resources.xml` anyway, as a fallback:

   ```
   if (!usedNewName) {
      // try to use sun-resources.xml
      registerResourceDir(resourceDir,dm,"sun-resources"); // NOI18N
    }
   ```

I should mention that this bug was introduced in NB 8.0; [7.3 doesn't appear to have the same problem](http://grepcode.com/file/bits.netbeans.org/maven2/org.netbeans.modules/org-netbeans-modules-glassfish-javaee/RELEASE731/org/netbeans/modules/glassfish/javaee/ResourceRegistrationHelper.java#143)

Answer (score 3):

For the record, I bumped in the same problem while going through the AffableBean tutorial with NetBeans 8.2 and Glassfish 5.0.

It appears that the glashfish-resources.xml file has been by default created under the web/WEB-INF folder. 
It is then ignored by Glassfish during the deploy phase.

Moving the file under the /setup directory via the "Files" window solve the problem and the resource and pool are created after a deploy launched via NetBeans.