# Deploy glassfish-resources.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

Is there anyway to automatically create resources mentioned in glassfish-resources.xml when the app is deploying. I know the way of creating resources via command line. But what i need is to create them automatically on the deploy

Answer (score 1):

**Deployment Descriptor**. An application-scoped resource is defined in the *glassfish-resources.xml* deployment descriptor file. This file is placed in the META-INF directory of the module or application archive. For web applications or modules, this file is placed in the WEB-INF directory. If any submodule archives of an enterprise application archive have their own *glassfish-resources.xml* files, the resource definitions are scoped to those modules only. For more information about the *glassfish-resources.xml* file, see [Appendix B, GlassFish Server Deployment Descriptor Files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/giida.html#scrolltoc) and [Appendix C, Elements of the GlassFish Server Deployment Descriptors](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beaqi.html#scrolltoc).

Read more at [Application-Scoped Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/giydj.html#scrolltoc).

Also check out (from the same guide) [Deploying a Connector Module](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/gilxc.html#scrolltoc)

You can also do it via annotations on a bean: [How to create a jms Topic and TopicConnectionFactory programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412513/how-to-create-a-jms-topic-and-topicconnectionfactory-programatically/8428206#8428206)